# Hoverable Metro UI Dropdown Menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, hover, click, metro-ui-css

I'm using Metro UI CSS 2.0 from https://metroui.org.ua/v2/ and use a menu bar.   Now I wanna make dropdown is auto on hover (now it just dropdown when click). I read the manual but cannot apply to that.
How can I make that hoverable ?
This is head:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta name="description" content="Metro, a sleek, intuitive, and powerful framework for faster and easier web development for Windows Metro Style.">
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, JS, JavaScript, framework, metro, front-end, frontend, web development">
<meta name="author" content="Sergey Pimenov and Metro UI CSS contributors">

<link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='../favicon.ico' />

<title>Template :: Metro UI CSS - The front-end framework for developing projects on the web in Windows Metro Style</title>

<link href="../css/metro.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/metro-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/metro-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="../js/metro.js"></script>

<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
    }
    .page-content {
        padding-top: 3.125rem;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .table .input-control.checkbox {
        line-height: 1;
        min-height: 0;
        height: auto;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px){
        #cell-sidebar {
            flex-basis: 52px;
        }
        #cell-content {
            flex-basis: calc(100% - 52px);
        }
    }
</style>
```

This is body:

```
<body class="bg-steel">
<nav class="app-bar fixed-top darcula" data-role="appbar">
    <a class="app-bar-element branding">BrandName</a>
    <span class="app-bar-divider"></span>
    <ul class="app-bar-menu">
        <li><a href="">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Project</a>
            <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">New project</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Reopen</a>
                    <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="">Project 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Project 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Project 3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="">Clear list</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Security</a></li>
        <li><a href="">System</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle">Help</a>
            <ul class="d-menu" data-role="dropdown">
                <li><a href="">ChatOn</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Community support</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="app-bar-element place-right">
        <span class="dropdown-toggle"><span class="mif-cog"></span> User Name</span>
        <div class="app-bar-drop-container padding10 place-right no-margin-top block-shadow fg-dark" data-role="dropdown" data-no-close="true" style="width: 220px">
            <h2 class="text-light">Quick settings</h2>
            <ul class="unstyled-list fg-dark">
                <li><a href="" class="fg-white1 fg-hover-yellow">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="fg-white2 fg-hover-yellow">Security</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="fg-white3 fg-hover-yellow">Exit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `class="dropdown-menu"` and `data-show="hover"` attribute to the dropdown menu (the `<ul>` element).

Comment: That is a manual on website.But when I add that attribute to <ul> : FROM <ul class="app-bar-menu"> TO <ul class="dropdown-menu" data-show="hover"> (no more change) , the menu can't use as dropdown => [link](goo.gl/photos/MB5VyJ2tJgsMtNAt6)

Comment: You can include more than one class per tag, separated by space as class="app-bar-menu dropdown-menu".

Comment: Thanks but I changed to <ul class="app-bar-menu dropdown-menu" data-show="hover"> and menu still not drop on hover. @_@

Comment: I just checked, there's no appbar on version 2. You are probably using v3. And I think that bar is not hoverable.

Comment: That's a bad news. Thank you for support.